# Function template with operator overloading

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning templates and came across function templates.I have developed the following code out of my creativity or just curiosity.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename type>
type Max(type a, type b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
class Foo
{
public:
    string s1;
    /*
    Foo& operator>(Foo &obj)
    {
        if (this->s1.length() > obj.s1.length() ? true : false)
            return *this;
        return obj;
    }*/
};
int main()
{
    cout << Max(2, 3) << endl;
    cout << Max(2.0, 3.0) << endl;
    Foo a, b;
    a.s1 = "AB";
    b.s1 = "ABC";
    //cout<<Max(a, b).s1;
}
```

My idea is to pass Foo objects a and b using the Max function template and overload the **'>'** operator and print the object's string with greater length.
Am i on the right path?Or should it be related to class templates?

Comment: `operator>` normally returns `bool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename type>
type Max(type a, type b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

class Foo {
public:
    string s1; 
    bool operator > (Foo &obj) {
        return this->s1.length() > obj.s1.length();         
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << Max(2, 3) << endl;
    cout << Max(2.0, 3.0) << endl;
    Foo a, b;
    a.s1 = "AB";
    b.s1 = "ABC";
    cout << Max(a, b).s1;
}
```

This maybe what you want: [image: output results]

Comment: :How come the function template is working with objects directly without making  changes like  type &Max(const type &a, const type &b).Why don't we need to change this?What's the internal functioning here?Please explain

Comment: Because we've overloaded the >, so the Max() will return the bigger object.We don't need to use referennce here.

Comment: @OMKAR By not using references (`&`), `Max()` is copying the `type` objects before doing the compare, then also copying the result. It works, but using references would be more efficient

Answer (score 2):

Let `operator>` return `bool`, otherwise it can't work with `return a > b ? a : b;`.

```
bool operator>(const Foo &obj)
{
    return this->s1.length() > obj.s1.length();
}
```

BTW1: `if (this->s1.length() > obj.s1.length() ? true : false)` is redundant.
BTW2: It's better to make the parameter type to `const` since `obj` won't and needn't be modified.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path, except that the `>` operator should take a `const` reference parameter, itself be a `const` class method, and return a `bool`:

```
bool operator>(const Foo &obj) const;
```

After all, what do you expect the result of `>` to be, with anything else, for example:

```
double a, b;

// ...

auto whatisthis= a > b;
```

Do you expect `whatisthis` to be a `double`? Of course not, it will be a `bool`. The result of any comparison operator, not only `>` should be a `bool`. It doesn't really have to be, you can overload the `>` operator and have it return anything; but that means that you couldn't use the way you expect to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is "Yes, you're on the right track."

The problem with generic functions is using them efficiently. Your `Max()` function works, but it copies Objects all over the place.

```
template <typename type>
const type &Max(const type &a, const type &b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

This solves the Object copying problem - but now it's less efficient for things like `int`s.